# Version is does not pull

Tags: git, version

I want to download the code from another branch:

Switching to my branch:

```
git checkout mybranch
```

Then performs a merge of the branch where wants to download the code:

```
git merge another_branch
```

Performs download:

```
git pull
```

I get the message that everything is up to date even though it is not.
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the "other_branch" is another branch that is hosted on the remote repository and that you also have some history of that branch in your local repo.

Try this:

`git checkout another_branch
git pull origin another_branch
git checkout mybranch
git merge another_branch`

This will :

- put you in your local version of `another_branch`
- pull any remote changes to `another_branch` to your local version
- put you in your local version of mybranch
- merge the local version of `another_branch` in the local version of mybranch

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer, but you can confirm your belief that repo is NOT up to date with remote.

```
A) Do `git remote -v` to verify remote repo config is correct.
B) Do `git describe` to see the HEAD of local repo.
C) Do `git ls-remote -h` to look at HEAD of remote.
```

B and C should have same SHA values. Do they have same SHA?